# python bisect is O(n^2)?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o, bisection

I'm running a simple test to monitor how long does it take to sort-insert into a list with the `bisect` library

```
import numpy as np
import bisect

def get_time(N):
    myl = []
    a = time.time()
    for i in np.arange(N):
        bisect.insort_left(myl, random.randint(0,1000000) )
    b = time.time()
    return (b-a)
```

So I call this with:

```
t_dict = {}
for N in [1000,5000,10000,50000,100000,200000,300000,400000,500000]:
    t_dict[N] = get_time(N)
```

and plot the results:

[image]

I would have guessed/hoped that `insort` would be at max `O(nlog(n))`. From the documentation, one reads:

"Keep in mind that the O(log n) search is dominated by the slow O(n) insertion step."

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I was missing something extremely obvious. Anyway, I would like to update the question with the same thing using SortedList from the package SortedContainers:

[image]

very fast stuff!

Comment: `bisect` is O(logN), **insertion into a list** on the other hand is O(N).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bisect` is O(logN). However, **insertion into a list** is O(N). You do that N times.

From the [`bisect.insort_left()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort_left):

> Keep in mind that the O(log n) search is **dominated** by the slow O(n) insertion step.

So insertion is still O(N), the O(logN) search time is (asymptotically speaking) insignificant compared to that. So *overall*, your timed tests are taking N times O(N) == O(N^2) time.

Comment: yeah, but the plot is not a line, is it?

Comment: I linked the exact same comment from the documentation by the way :)

Comment: @elelias you are repeating an O(N) insertion N times. That makes the overall process O(N^2)

Comment: aaaah, now I get what you are saying. Indeed, makes sense thanks.

Comment: @elelias: and I did miss you quoted the same comment, so I now emphasised the part of that comment you missed. :-)